# Is it properly closing connection from ASP.Net to SQL SERVER

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, memory-leaks, database-connection, connection-pooling

Is the below piece of code closing the connection properly..

```
public static bool Hello(string sqlQuery)
        {
            SqlDataReader dataReader = null;
            var isExist = false;

            using (var aeConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    var aeCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, aeConnection)
                        {
                            CommandType = CommandType.Text
                        };

                    aeConnection.Open();
                    dataReader = aeCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default);

                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                       int vinCount;
                        int.TryParse(dataReader["VINCount"].ToString(), out vinCount);

                        if (vinCount == 0)
                        {
                          isExist = true;
                         }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   if (dataReader != null)
                   {
                       dataReader.Close();
                   }
                }
            }

            return isExist;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is properly closing connection.When the using block is exited (either by successful completion or by error) it is closed.

The using statement gets compiled into a try/finally block

```
using (var aeConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
}
```

It will treated as

```
SqlConnection aeConnection = null;
try
{
    aeConnection  = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
}
finally
{
   if(aeConnection!= null)
        ((IDisposable)aeConnection).Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I am worried about this line..`var aeCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, aeConnection)` as I got a connection pool zammed error in my site now..and this is max query code..

Comment: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached

Comment: Seems you are not closing the datareader after its use, this may be one of the reason for getting above exception. Close this datareader object after its use.

Comment: yes..its is not closed in finally..instead it is closed in catch block..and this executed n number of times on my server

Comment: Do you think this is a POTENTIAL reason for this? - I edited the code

Comment: Yes this could be one of the reason. Close this object  in finally block and see the effect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37252/discussion-between-james-and-pawan)